# How do I make Git hub automatically sync

Tags: git, github

I have a project I'm trying to test and me and a friend are both editing the code via FTP and it's not working out, we've thought of using Git Hub to upload our changes and then syncing for a server where we can both test it, how ever it's not pulling the updates automatically like we had wanted, I've looked around and most the solutions are scripts for Linux and other things that don't work on windows.

Is there a way this could work or is there something else I could use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+automatic+git ? Have you been able to try anything?

Comment: What did you try that didn't pull the updates?

Comment: Well we have to pull the updates every few minutes for our test server, we've thought about a SVN or something like that that updates it as soon as it's changed.. Oh, just git's pull function, we're not sure what else to do really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your test server to be regularly and automatically updated with new code, your best bet is likely to use GitHub's service integrations.

For example, you can set up a service integration such that GitHub will notify a Jenkins build server every time somebody pushes updates to your `master` branch. Jenkins can then fetch the latest code, run tests, and deploy to your test server.

I don't know specifically *how* you intend to deploy changes to your test server, but there are a huge number of service integrations that you can set up by going to your repository's **Settings** page, then clicking **Webhooks & Services**, then **Configure services**. One of them will likely fit your needs.

If nothing there looks like a good fit, you can roll your own solution using [Webhooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).

If you're looking for something simpler, you could always schedule a job on your server to run `git pull` every 15 minutes using `cron`.